# What is Magento's index_event table

Tags: performance, magento, indexing

I'm playing with improving performance during saving category and I found that once category is updated via Magenti API or backend then the following update query is called

```
SQL: UPDATE `index_event` SET `event_id` = ?, `type` = ?, `entity` = ?, `entity_pk` = ?, `created_at` = ?, `old_data` = ?, `new_data` = ? WHERE (event_id='13066')
BIND: Array
(
    [0] => 13066
    [1] => save
    [2] => catalog_category
    [3] => 2867
    [4] => 2011-09-22 13:50:54
    [5] => a:4:{s:30:"Mage_Catalog_Model_Indexer_Url";N;s:40:"Mage_Catalog_Model_Category_Indexer_Flat";N;s:43:"Mage_Catalog_Model_Category_Indexer_Product";N;s:41:"Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Indexer_Fulltext";N;}
    [6] => a:11:{s:35:"cataloginventory_stock_match_result";b:0;s:34:"catalog_product_price_match_result";b:0;s:24:"catalog_url_match_result";b:1;s:30:"Mage_Catalog_Model_Indexer_Url";N;s:33:"catalog_product_flat_match_result";b:0;s:34:"catalog_category_flat_match_result";b:1;s:40:"Mage_Catalog_Model_Category_Indexer_Flat";N;s:37:"catalog_category_product_match_result";b:1;s:43:"Mage_Catalog_Model_Category_Indexer_Product";N;s:35:"catalogsearch_fulltext_match_result";b:1;s:41:"Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Indexer_Fulltext";N;}
```

Can anyone tell me what does it mean and will happen? It looks like some indexing actions are pushed to a queue but when does it execute?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Your assumption *"It looks like some indexing actions are pushed to a queue"* is correct.

To answer your question *"but when does it execute?"*:

Some Magento models, like

```
Mage_Core_Model_Store
Mage_Catalog_Model_Product
Mage_Catalog_Model_Category
Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock_Item
Mage_Tag_Model_Tag
Mage_Tag_Model_Tag_Relation
```

for example, queue index events. Mainly before deleting and/or after committing.

They do this by either calling the `logEvent()` or the `processEntityAction()` method of the `Mage_Index_Model_Indexer` class.

- If they call `logEvent()` directly, an index event will only be queued. Reindexing will not even be tried.
- If they call `processEntityAction()`, also an index event will be queued, but Magento will try to process this index event right after queueing.

There's also a third method `Mage_Index_Model_Indexer::indexEvents()` being called by some modules. The difference to the former two is, that `indexEvents()` does *not* queue any index event, but will only try to immediately reindex.

Note that any reindexing thru `processEntityAction()` and `indexEvents()` will only happen, if the process mode of the corresponding index type is `Mage_Index_Model_Process::MODE_REAL_TIME`.

You can check this via `System -> Index Management`. If the `Mode` column reads *Update on save*, than that index is set to `MODE_REAL_TIME`.

If it reads *Manual Update* instead, it's set to `Mage_Index_Model_Process::MODE_MANUAL`, which means automatic reindexing will never happen at all.

In the latter case you need to manually trigger the reindexing processes to get your data reindexed. That can be achieved using several methods, e.g. by using `System -> Index Management -> Index -> Reindex data -> Submit`, or using the Magento `shell/indexer.php` on the command line, or by scripting your own indexer process collection handling started by a cron job.

Comment: Have you heard of any magento modifications that could allow things to queue and then process those via the shell indexer at a certain time? Indexers are a major pain point with our store.

Comment: A bit of an old post, but for anyone who is looking - there are plugins out there that delay indexing for a later time to speed up  the admin panel product/category manipulations. e.g. [Mirasvit's Asynchronous Re-indexing](http://mirasvit.com/magento-extensions/magento-asynchronous-reindex.html)

Comment: very well explained.